# I'm getting the following exception- java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

getting the following error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-servlet] in context with path [/sigma] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT
```

getting error at line

```
FallbackPnr fallbackPnr = entityManager.find(FallbackPnr.class, searchDate, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
```

getting LockModeType from javaee-api-7.0.jar

FallBackPnr.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name= "super_pnr_counter")
public class FallbackPnr {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @Column(name="version")
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    private Date updatedOn;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/6252754

Comment: I have included all the necessary jars.